# How to toggle a div based on a select box value change inside same component in ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to ember. I have two divs with a select box each. I want the second div to toggle based on the change in the first select box value.

First DIV with select box:

```
        <div class="row row-space">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-addon edit_schedule_label" id="sizing-addon3">Schedule Level</span>
                    <div class="recurrence_box">
                        {{view "select" content=schedule_levels optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label" selection="default_schedule_level.value" value="default_schedule_level.value" selectionBinding="default_schedule_level"}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Second DIV:

```
        {{#if group_level_decider }}
            <div class="row row-space">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon edit_schedule_label" id="sizing-addon3">Location </span>
                        <div class="recurrence_box">
                            {{view "select" content=schedule_levels optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label" selection="default_schedule_level.value" value="default_schedule_level.value" selectionBinding="default_schedule_level"}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
```

In Controller, I am observing the change in selection binding of the first select box and setting the condition to toggle for the second div. I can see the condition variable here "group_level_decider" getting set to the correct value but it is not reflecting in the view.

Controller:

```
       group_level_decider : false,
       schedule_level_changed: function() {
          var model = this.get('store');
          model.set('selected_schedule_level',this.get('default_schedule_level.value'))

          model.set('group_level_decider',true)

       }.observes('default_schedule_level')
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of filtering out cities based on a state:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  cities: function(){
    var state = this.get('state');
    var states = this.get('model');

    var cities = [];

    if(state){
      cities = states.filterBy('state', state).get(0).get('cities');
    }

    return cities;
 }.property('state'),

 states: function(){
   return this.get('model').mapBy('state');
 }.property(),

 stateObserver: function(){
   this.set('city', null);
 }.observes('state')

});
```

Then, inside your template:

```
States: {{view "select" prompt="Pick State..." content=states value=state}}
Cities: {{view "select" prompt="Pick City..." content=cities value=city }}
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoxepi/2/edit?html,js,output)